# Connecting 2 iPads with a router without internet

Tags: ipad, wifi, router

I need to connect two iPads to a network without internet connection. Can I just do it with a simple router? Is there a good type of router to share data without internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this of course.  Any wifi router that the two iPads both support should connect them.  Just don't bother to connect to the Internet.

I'm curious as to why you need this? Most iOS apps don't do peer to peer, though some obviously do.  Bittorrent Sync for one would possibly be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your goal is: You might not even need a router. Open a Personal Hotspot on one iPad (assuming it has 3G) and connect to it with the other one. You get the IP addresses of both in the WIFI settings of the second iPad.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply sharing files, use AirDrop. Swipe up, and tap the AirDrop button.

For a Peer-to-Peer network, you can use your Mac as a router. Caveat: Your Mac must have a working Ethernet cable plugged in, but the iPads will not have an internet connection.

Open System Preferences > Sharing > click the lock icon to authenticate. Select "Internet Sharing" from the field on the left. From the "Share your connection from:" drop-down, select "Ethernet," and in the "To computers using:" field select "Wi-Fi." Now click the "Wi-Fi Options" button to set a network name and password. When done, click "OK". Tick the box in the left field next to "Internet Sharing, then click "Start" on the menu that appears.

On each iPad, go to Settings > Wi-Fi, select the network you just named and connect to it. After you connect, tap the (i) next to the Wi-Fi signal for that network. Copy the IP Address, Subnet Mask, and Router to "Static". You can tap back and forth between the "DHCP" (default) tab, and "Static". For DNS, enter "0.0.0.0" and exit settings.

Both iPads will now be able to access each other and your Mac*, but will not have internet access.

- I just tested this using a VNC connection to view my Mac. This only works if you have "Screen Sharing" turned on in "Sharing".